# Is there any similar function in MATLAB like enumerate()

Tags: python, matlab

This is a python code. I want to convert this code into MATLAB and 'for' loop in one line but I can't.

calibration = {'rms': result[0], 'camera_matrix': result[1].tolist(), 'dist_coefs':result[2].tolist(), 'rotational_vectors': {("image" + str(c)): x.tolist() for c, x in **enumerate**(result[3])},'translational_vectors': {("image" + str(c)): x.tolist() for c, x in **enumerate**(result[4])},'image_files_names': [[c, x] for c, x in **enumerate**(imageFileNames)]}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab equivalent of Python enumerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469168/matlab-equivalent-of-python-enumerate)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, while I learned MATLAB, I don't remember any function similar to enumerate() in Python for MATLAB

Maybe you can define your own function enumerate and use it as and when you want by defining it earlier on simply creating a custom package (toolbox)

Here's how I would create an enumerate() function for MATLAB:

```
classdef enumerate < handle
   properties(Access = private)
      IterationList;
   end
   
   methods 
       function self = enumerate(in)
           self.IterationList = in;
       end
       function [varargout] = subsref(self, S)
           item = subsref(self.IterationList,S);
           num = S.subs{2};
           out.item = item;
           out.num = num;
           varargout = {out};
       end
       function [m,n] = size(self)
           [m,n] = size(self.IterationList);
       end
   end
end
```

Once defined, simply use it to your liking like:

```
for t = enumerate(linspace(0,1,10));
disp(['Number: ',num2str(t.num),'Item: ',num2str(t.item)]); 
end
```

How to create a MATLAB Custom Toolbox [Check this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-and-share-custom-matlab-toolboxes.html)

Alternatively if you have a 1D Array:

```
enumerate = @(values) [1:length(values); values]

a = [6 5 4]
for i=enumerate(a)
    do something with i
end
```

Also there's some documentation about enumerations for MATAB r2021a
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/enumeration-classes.html

Additional sources: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html

Comment: This is really nice! Your link to enumeration classes is unrelated though. That’s a way to give a name to a series of numbers, equivalent to Python [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

Comment: Indeed @CrisLuengo, realized it later on...!